# Haskell: Parsec trouble breaking out of pattern

Tags: haskell, parsec

For reference, here is my code: http://hpaste.org/86949

I am trying to parse the following expression: `if (a[1].b[2].c.d[999].e[1+1].f > 3) { }`. The method playing up is `varExpr`, which parses the variable member chains.

**Context**

In the language I am parsing, a dot can specify accessing a member variable. Since a member variable can be another object, chains can be produced ie: `a.b.c`, or essentially `(a.b).c`. Do not assume the dots are function composition.

**Implementation**

The logic is like this:

- First, `before <- many vocc` collects all the instances of `varname .` and their optional array expression, leaving only a single identifier left
- `this <- vtrm` collects the remaining identifier plus array expression -- the only one not proceeded by a dot

**Issues**

I am having two issues:

Firstly, the first term [for a reason that I cannot determine] seems to always require that it be wrapped in brackets for the parser to accept it ie: `(a[1]).b[2].c...` -- subsequent terms do not require this.

Secondly, the `many vocc` won't stop parsing. It always expects another identifier and another dot and I am unable to terminate the expression to catch the last `vtrm`.

I am looking for hints or solutions that will help me solve my problem(s)/headaches. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `varExpr` runs, it checks whether the next bit of input is matched by `vocc` or `vtrm`.

```
varExpr = do before <- many vocc  -- Zero or more occurrences
             this <- vtrm
             return undefined
```

The problem is that any input matched by `vtrm` is also matched by the first step of `vocc`.  When `varExpr` runs, it runs `vocc`, which runs `vobj`, which runs `vtrm`.

```
vocc = vobj <* symbol "."
vobj = choice [try vtrm, try $ parens vtrm]
```

Parsing of `many vocc` ends when `vocc` fails without consuming input.  This happens when both `vtrm` and `parens vtrm` fail.  However, after `many vocc` ends, the next parser to run is `vtrm`—and this parser is sure to fail!

You want `vocc` to fail without consuming input if it doesn't find a `"."` in the input.  For that, you need to use `try`.

```
vocc = try $ vobj <* symbol "."
```

Alternatively, if `vobj` and `vtrm` really should be the same syntax, you can define varExpr as `` vobj `sepBy1` symbol "." ``.

Comment: Worked a charm! Any idea why the first term always needs parens around it?

Comment: When I tested `varExpr` on its own, the first term didn't need parentheses.  I guess that there is overlap between `varExpr` and `callExpr`, similar to the overlap between `vocc` and `vtrm`.  Try using `try` with `callExpr`.